# MySQL : Request to make an JSON object with Array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, json

Ok, I have a simple question...
I have a database with two tables :

> Articles (id, content, title, date)
>
> Comments (id_article, username, content)

And I want to obtain a JSON array like this :

```
[
    {
    "id": "5785634a87c5a0075bf211de",
    "title": "Elita",
    "content": "Commodo ea enim dolor enim adipisicing ut mollit .",
    "date":"15July2016"
    "comments": [
        {
        "username": "Tran",
        "content": "Ea aliqua sit fugiat adipisicing."
        },
        {
        "username": "Noreen",
        "content": "Commodo qui ea nulla est officia. non."
        },
        {
        "username": "Gilliam",
        "content": "Esse cupidatat adipisicing sit minim."
        }
    ]
    }
]
```

So my question ... Is it possible with only one request? :) Thanks you

Comment: Yes. You have to make the MySQL query joining the tables. With the result of that query you create an assotiative array in PHP and return it as a JSON.
So if the question is 'Is it possible?', then Yes. If you want more technical details let me know. Good luck!

Comment: Wow thanks for your answer @SrAxi if that could be possible to get more details (technical) it would be a pleasure ;) Thanks

Comment: I've tried to make a join (outer join I think) but when i do that I only have one  comment to the article... I can make two request, one for the article and one for the comments, make a script php to join them and threw it as JSON, but I was thinking about the possibility to make that in sql ... ;)

Comment: Working on it! Will answer soon! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can LEFT JOIN to get all the data you need, when iterating over it you just have to take care about how you handle which data.

```
$lastArticleId = null;
$comments = [];
$elements = [];
$sql = 'SELECT Articles.*, Comments.content AS comment, Comments.username FROM Articles LEFT JOIN Comments ON Articles.id = Comments.id_article';
$result = $pdo->query($sql);
foreach ($result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) as $dataset) {
    if($lastArticleId !== $dataset->id){
        $lastArticleId = $dataset->id;
        $elements[$lastArticleId] = [
            'id'       => $dataset->id,
            'title'    => $dataset->title,
            'content'  => $dataset->content,
            'date'     => $dataset->date,
            'comments' => [],
        ];
    }
    $comments[$lastArticleId][] = [
        'content' => $dataset->comment,
        'username' => $dataset->username,
    ];
}
foreach ($elements as $key => $article) {
    $article['comments'] = $comments[$key];
    $fullData[] = $article;
}
echo json_encode($fullData);
```

**But**: Just because you can, doesn't mean you should.

Splitting this task in two queries is a lot easier to write and to read. So if you later for some reason need to touch this piece of code (or someone else) he will be glad you chose the 2 query approach.

Also it is good practice to split tasks, so ideally you would create methods in your database-access-layer `getAllArticles()` and another one `getCommentsByArticleId($id_article)`. This way you could fetch all the comments, without having to load the whole article.

Comment: Hmmm just with my curiosity I'll test it later... Thanks for your help!
That seems good, you're awesome :)

Comment: Ah btw, in the german php community this is known as "Gruppenbruch" -> "breaking (into) groups"; as you split the whole data by a specific criteria into groups. http://php-de.github.io/jumpto/gruppenbruch/#beispiel-1b the text around is german but you should check this simple example

Comment: Ok I will looking at it... Thanks for your code, it works perfectly ;)

Comment: @Philipp Brilliant approach. I always try to split tasks. I always try to have a method for each task. It is better to develop and then to maintain. But the question here was to make this in 1 query. And you did. Nice! ;)

Answer (score 1):

At the end, you will need to do 2 queries, -.-'

Here would be the PHP code (getJSON.php, for example):

```
$array = [];
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM Articles';
$q = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error in $sql: ".mysql_error());
while ($rs = mysql_fetch_object($q)) {
    $element = [
        'id'       => $rs->id,
        'title'    => $rs->title,
        'content'  => $rs->content,
        'date'     => $rs->date,
        'comments' => [],
    ];

    $sql2 = 'SELECT * FROM Comments WHERE id_article = '.$rs->id;
    $q2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die ("Error in $sql2: ".mysql_error());
    while ($rs2 = mysql_fetch_object($q2)) {
        $comment = [
            'username' => $rs2->username,
            'content' => $rs2->content,
        ];

        $element['comments'] = $comment;
    }

    $array[] = $element;
}

echo json_encode($array);
```

And this could be like the jQuery or Javascript call to obtain that JSON generated in the php script:

```
jQuery.getJSON('getJSON.php', {}, function (data) {}
```

And well, then the rest you already have it I guess...

I hope it helped you. Let me know! And good luck! ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot ;) Ok I so I will do that. You're a boss!

Comment: Let me know how it goes man. Check this: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/  For the JSON handling.

Comment: A second query should not be necessary

Comment: @Philipp How would you loop through all the records of the table `Comments` for each article in the `Articles` table? Doing that with 1 query?

Comment: The `join` will give you the datasets, the information of the article itself will be repeated in every returned row, but as you only have to work with it once it doesn't really matter. After fetching you loop over the resultset to put the comments-data into an array, after the last iteration you can then work with the articledata of the last iteration and put them together. When handling multiple articles you just have to place that step into the beginning and check each iteration if you are working on the next article. Gonna extend my answer

Comment: @Philipp You were assigning values in `$element` outside the `foreach`, that way `$dataset` is undefined. 
I don't want to bring your theory down, because I'm interested on doing it on 1 query. I would like to see a working example of your theory, it would be great for me! :D

Comment: @Philipp I'm Curious now, I know that I had to do 2 queries... The thing is that I was thinking about making only one so yes, If you have an example it would be great :) Thanks a lot guys! Oh and Btw SrAxi, I know getJSON, but I'm using Angular to get it ($http.get)

Comment: Edited the answer. @SrAxi $dataset doesn't get undefined after the loop, it will just keep it's values of the last iteration :)

Comment: @Philipp Brilliant! Thank you!