# How to group data with MySQL + Php?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to extract and display some info from my database. My problem is: the column 'fatura'(in table A) always will be linked to multiples 'stur' rows (in table B). I can't find how to not display the same 'fatura' for each 'stur'.

***My code:***

```
<?php
$mysqli = NEW MySQLi('localhost','root','','server');

$sqlFatura = $mysqli->query("SELECT fatura,stur 
                             FROM faturas inner join anexos
                             WHERE ID_fatura = FK_fatura 
                             ");


if($sqlFatura->num_rows > 0){
    while($rows = $sqlFatura->fetch_assoc()){
        $fatura = $rows['fatura'];
        $stur = $rows['stur'];     

        echo "<p> Fatura $fatura => Stur: $stur </p>";
?>
```

Result right now:

```
 'Fatura FT01 => Stur 01
  Fatura FT01 => Stur 02
  Fatura FT01 => Stur 03
  Fatura FT02 => Stur 04
  Fatura FT02 => Stur 05'
```

Need to be :

```
  'Fatura FT01 => Stur 01, 02, 03
   Fatura FT02 => Stur 04, 05
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what does your `stur` column contain? show one or two of such data

Answer (score 3):

You can try using `GROUP BY ID_fatura` along with `GROUP_CONCAT(stur)`.

```
SELECT
    fatura,
    GROUP_CONCAT(stur) AS allSturs
FROM
    faturas
INNER JOIN anexos ON ID_fatura = FK_fatura
GROUP BY ID_fatura
```

**Note:** Since column name of `stur` changed to `allSturs` so you need to change the line where you are getting the value of it.

`$stur = $rows['allSturs'];`

**Caution:**

> Beware of `MySQL` **max size** for a string variable and `GROUP_CONCAT`.
>
> If `GROUP_CONCAT` max length is the limit (1024 by default) you should
>   alter the temporary setting (session-scope) for length of it. It's
>   done by:
>
> `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 10000`

[*Set group_concat_max_len permanently (MySQL config)*](https://serverfault.com/questions/346866/set-group-concat-max-len-permanently-mysql-config)

Comment: I was focusing on the php side, your method worked perfectly. The stur field are document numbers of a process.I was frying my brains here,  thank you a lot for the help!

Comment: Please practice marking answer as **accepted** if it works for you so that others find it useful. [**How to accept answer**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: So... I need to turn every single "stur" register into a link (to a unique document). How can I do this? Everything a tried turned the whole string into a link. 

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry didn't understand what you asked for

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick example of how you could do this with php. (had to create the arrays first and switch to a foreach loop though, to properly recreate your scenario)

You can see, it is a little more work than when solving the problem directly in mysql, but might be you some day have to use something like this. Also I didn't set the "," after the "stur"-numbers, this would take some more work again.

You can also see this [answer about how to break those groups into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38400664/3595565)

```
$faturas = array(
 array('fatura' => 'Fatura FT01', 'stur' => '01'),
 array('fatura' => 'Fatura FT01', 'stur' => '02'),
 array('fatura' => 'Fatura FT01', 'stur' => '03'),
 array('fatura' => 'Fatura FT02', 'stur' => '04'),
 array('fatura' => 'Fatura FT02', 'stur' => '05'),
);

$firstIteration === true;
foreach ($faturas as $rows) {
    if($lastFatura !== $rows['fatura']){
        if($firstIteration === false){
            echo '</p>';
        }
        echo '<p>Fatura' . $rows['fatura'] . ' => Stur';
        $lastFatura = $rows['fatura'];
    }
    $firstIteration = false;
    echo ' ' . $rows['stur'];
}
```